# How to generate reset password token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise gem for authentication.

In my application admin will create the users, so I want the user's reset password link when admin creates users.

This is my action:-

```
def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   @user.password = '123123123'
   @user.password_confirmation = '123123123'
   if @user.save
         @user.update_attributes(:confirmation_token => nil,:confirmed_at => Time.now,:reset_password_token => (0...16).map{(65+rand(26)).chr}.join,:reset_password_sent_at => Time.now)
       UserMailer.user_link(@user).deliver
       redirect_to users_path
     else
    render :action => "new"
   end
end
```

This is my link to reset a user's password

But I am getting reset password token is invalid when I open the link and update the password.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `user.send_reset_password_instructions` for that.

Comment: where should i use this?

Comment: i can't get devise to use the right mailer... i need to just generate the token

Answer (score 53):

If you are using devise why are you creating your own password reset token?
Devise has a feature for that.
http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable

In case you wonder this is what devise does when the user wants to reset his password:

```
  raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)

  self.reset_password_token   = enc
  self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  self.save(validate: false)
```

self is a User object here

In your URL you then have to pass raw as reset_password_token parameter

Answer (score 23):

You can generate a token with:

```
Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
```

Though this is just a useless string by itself. You need to attach it to the user if you actually want to use it in a link to reset passwords:

```
user.reset_password_token = hashed_token
user.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
```

Then send them an email with the link:

```
edit_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @token)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want it to send the instructions, just set and store the token you can call the private method in devise `recoverable` concern `set_reset_password_token`.

You can do this by doing something like `user.send(:set_reset_password_token)`.

Answer (score 4):

To get the url to reset the password using Devise I use this snippet of code:

```
user = User.find(id)
raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
user.update_columns(reset_password_token: enc, reset_password_sent_at: Time.current)
puts Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_user_password_url(reset_password_token: raw, host: 'localhost:3000')
```

Comment: This worked great - thanks.  When sending my reset email, I had to make sure `@token` was the `raw`, not `enc`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon [@Rails Fan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604536/939299). The specific method that handles the password reset in `Recoverable` module is a protected method [set_reset_password_token](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L89) .

You can access it by the following code and it will return the token directly.

```
## your model.send(:set_reset_password_token)
user.send(:set_reset_password_token)
```